# How to redirect one of several inputs?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In Linux/Unix command line, when using a command with multiple inputs, how can I redirect one of them?

For example, say I'm using `cat` to concatenate multiple files, but I only want the last few lines of one file, so my inputs are `testinput1`, `testinput2`, and `tail -n 4 testinput3`.

How can I do this in one line without any temporary files?

I tried `tail -n 4 testinput3 | cat testinput1 testinput2`, but this seems to just take in input 1 and 2.

Sorry for the bad title, I wasn't sure how to phrase it exactly.

Comment: you can use [process substutution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Comment: @ymonad I tried `cat testinput1 testinput2 <tail -n 4 testinput3`, but as expected, that told me `-bash: tail: No such file or directory`.

Comment: You forgot the parents `<(process)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried `cat testinput1 testinput2 < <(tail -n 4 testinput3)`, but that only gave me the output of the first two, just like when I tried to use piping.

Comment: Sorry, see updated comment, you do not need the extra redirection `cat file1 file2 <(tail -n4 file3)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, that works. You could post that as an answer if you want.

Comment: ++ for process substitution, but `tail -n 4 testinput3 | cat - testinput1 testinput2` might work, and is more backwards compatible with older or more limited shells. The `-` means "read-from-std-in", which in this case is the std-out from `tail`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to pipe the output of `tail` to `cat`, bash provides *process substitution* where the process substitution is run with its input or output connected to a FIFO or a file in `/dev/fd` (like your terminal tty). This allows you to treat the output of a process as if it were a file.

In the normal case you will generally redirect the output of the process substitution into a loop, e.g, `while read -r line; do ##stuff; done < <(process)`. However, in your case, `cat` takes the file itself as an argument rather than reading from `stdin`, so you omit the initial redirection, e.g.

```
cat file1 file2 <(tail -n4 file3)
```

So be familiar with both forms, `< <(process)` if you need to redirect a process as input or simply `<(process)` if you need the result of process to be treated as a file.